# Invalid Path in Cookie constructor C#

Tags: c#, exception, cookies, restsharp

When adding new aquired cookies from RestResponse I have strange problem with cookies from wiedzmin.wikia.com .

The Exception Message is

" The 'Path'='/wiki/Specjalna:Nowe_pliki' part of the cookie is invalid. "

```
foreach (RestSharp.RestResponseCookie buiscuit in responce.Cookies)
{
    cookies.Add(new Uri(pageURL), new Cookie(buiscuit.Name, buiscuit.Value,
    buiscuit.Path, buiscuit.Domain));
}
```

The values of buiscuit are:

```
Name = loadtime
Value = S1342001743.657154083
Path = /wiki/Specjalna:Nowe_pliki
Domain = wiedzmin.wikia.com
```

MS VS 10 say it may be something with a size of a cookie. Is it true?